# How to find ranks for only students who got pass marks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have student marks in one database table, like

```
studid, studname, m1, m2, m3
```

and students' personal information in another database table, like

```
studid, studname.
```

- I want to join both tables to get studid, studname, ((m1,m2,m3) must be sum as 'total').

  The students' results must display if m1,m2,m3<40 then fail else pass.
- I also want to display the rank for only students those who got pass marks.

Comment: can you post your full tables and example data and an expected result with that data

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: the result must be like this.
studid   studname   m1  m2  m3  total    result   rank
101         arjun         60   48   66    174   pass     3
102         kumar       70   55   80     205  pass     1
103         Arun          55   60   58    173   pass     2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID, Name, CASE WHEN total > 40 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'fail' end from 
(select m.studid as ID, m.studname as Name, sum(m1)+sum(m2)+sum(m3) as total from marks m NATURAL JOIN info i group by studid,studname )
```

Comment: I also want to find the rank positions who got pass marks only

Comment: Im using Sql Server 2008 Management studio

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select studID, Studname, m1, m2, m3, (m1+ m2+ m3) as 'Total', 
    case 
        when(m1<40 OR m2<40 OR m3<40) 
        then 'FAIL' 
        else 'PASS' 
    end as 'Result'
```

it should work. you can join 2 tables to produce the desire results

Comment: I need query to get ranks only for pass students. can you please help me

Comment: Thanks but it takes result fail as 3rd rank like this 101 Arjun 229 PASS 1 108 Francis 222 PASS 2 109 John 210 FAIL NULL 106 Venkatesh 202 PASS 4 103 Perumal 201 PASS 5 105 Siva 199 PASS 6 104 Vignesh 180 PASS 7 110 Wesly 177 FAIL NULL 107 Vijay 166 PASS 9 102 Kumar 152 PASS 10 I need to display rank for only pass marks..

Comment: I want the result like this 
studid       studname        total        results        rank 
101              Arjun            229          pass            1 
108             Francis         222            pass           2 Fail students should not considered...

Comment: Add where condition to the query to filter out the result. select studID, Studname, m1, m2, m3, (m1+ m2+ m3) as 'Total', 
    case 
        when(m1<40 or m2<40 or m3<40) 
        then 'FAIL' 
        else 'PASS' 
    end as 'Result' from marks where m1>=40 and m2>=40 and m3>=40 order by total

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` with `CASE` like this.

```
SELECT studid, studname,(m1 + m2 + m3) as Totalmarks,
CASE WHEN (m1 >= 40 AND m2 >= 40 AND m3 >= 40) THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END,
CASE WHEN (m1 >= 40 AND m2 >= 40 AND m3 >= 40) THEN DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY (m1 + m2 + m3) DESC) ELSE NULL END std_rank
FROM studentmarks
WHERE m1 >= 40 AND m2 >= 40 AND m3 >= 40
```

**EDIT**

If you want to show all students remove the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thanks but it takes result fail as 3rd rank like this

101 Arjun 229 PASS 1
108 Francis 222 PASS 2
109 John 210 FAIL NULL
106 Venkatesh 202 PASS 4
103 Perumal 201 PASS 5
105 Siva 199 PASS 6
104 Vignesh 180 PASS 7
110 Wesly 177 FAIL NULL
107 Vijay 166 PASS 9
102 Kumar 152 PASS 10



I need to display rank for only pass marks..

Comment: I want the result like this

studid    studname    total    results   rank
101        Arjun           229      pass       1
108        Francis        222      pass       2


Fail students should not considered...

Comment: if you want exclude failed results then add a filter `WHERE m1 >= 40 AND m2 >= 40 AND m3 >= 40`.  In such a case only pass students will be listed